# Create IO bound observable with RX

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, io, system.reactive

I have a worker thread making blocking calls (`ReadFrame`) 
to read incoming data from a socket (IO bound).
The thread runs a loop, that feeds the data into an `Subject`,
that can be observed by consumers.

```
private void ReadLoop()
{
    while (!IsDisposed)
    {
        var frame = _Socket.ReadFrame();
        _ReceivedFrames.OnNext(frame);
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a more RX kind of way to do this.

Here is an attempt (toy example) I made:

```
var src = Observable
         .Repeat(Unit.Default)
         .Select(_ =>
         {
             Thread.Sleep(1000);              // simulated blocking ReadFrame call
             return "data read from socket";
         })
         .SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance) // avoid blocking when subscribing
         .ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)     // spin up new thread (?)
         .Publish()
         .RefCount();

var d = src.Subscribe(s => s.Dump()); // simulated consumer

Console.ReadLine();  // simulated main running code

d.Dispose();  // tear down
```

I'm struggling with the correct use of `ObserveOn`, `SubscribeOn` and the schedulers.
The toy example seems to work, but I'm not sure if the thread's lifetime is managed correctly.

Is the reader thread shut down with the `d.Dispose()` call?
Do I need to create a new thread at all?
Should I use `Observable.Create` instead? How?

> Below additional info requested by @Enigmativity:

The `ReadLoop()` method is part of a class that conforms to the following interface:

```
public interface ICanSocket : IDisposable
{
    IObservable<CanFrame> ReceivedFrames { get; }
    IObserver<CanFrame>   FramesToSend   { get; }
}
```

Its member `_Socket` is disposed (closed) when the parent `ICanSocket` is disposed.

Comment: What is your `_Socket` type and what does `ReadFrame()` look like?

Comment: `_Socket` is a wrapper around a [BSD Socket](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket). `ReadFrame()` calls [read(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read). I don't think, that those details are relevant to the (more general) problem at hand though (IO bound producer).

Comment: The way you've created the observable isn't the correct way of doing things, but because it is a socket it's hard to tell if `Observable.Create` or `Observable.Using` would be the best approach. So the details are relevant. Can you let us know how to set up your project so that we have compilable code?

Comment: The project setup is complicated. It involves compiling a .c file with gcc, a C# class with P/Invoke, plus it must run on mono/linux. Can't we just pretend that `ReadFrame()` reads chunks of data from a slow disk? I think the outcome will be the same...

Comment: No, it's not. You need to encapsulate state within the observable and the observable needs to manage the lifetime of the socket. We need to at least know the signature of your socket class to help.

Comment: Ok, I added the interface of the socket. Does that help?

Comment: So you've written that class yourself? So I take it that there is an underlying "BSD Socket" class?

Comment: Having had another look at your `ICanSocket` it appears you've given me the interface of the class that you **want to implement**. I need to know the interface of the "BSD Socket" that you're wrapping around.

Answer (score 1):

The most "Rxy" way to do this is to use [Rxx](https://rxx.codeplex.com/), which has observable methods for doing async I/O.

Seems like your primary concerns are:

- When subscribing, do not block the subscriber thread (aka run the I/O thread on a background thread)
- When the caller unsubscribes, stop the I/O thread

One way to solve these is to just use the async Create method:

```
// just use Task.Run to "background" the work
var src = Observable
    .Create<CanFrame>((observer, cancellationToken) => Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var frame = _Socket.ReadFrame();
            if (frame == null) // end of stream?
            {
                // will send a Completed event
                return;
            }

            observer.OnNext(frame);
        }
    }));

var d = src.Subscribe(s => s.Dump());
Console.ReadLine();
d.Dispose();
```

Comment: Doesn't that create a new task for every subscriber? If true, the subscribers would steal each others frames. Also, which methods of Rxx do you think of?

Comment: Yes it does. Append a `.Publish().RefCount()` if you want multiple observers to share the same stream.

Comment: I haven't used Rxx in a while. Look for Socket and Stream. It has a number of methods that take  these as input and return an observable of the data.